# Group Rights - Cache

Tags: 2013, web8, content-manager

I created blueprint in Tridion.

- Empty Master
- Content English

There is also Group "SpecialUser"

At the moment of creation the publication "Content English", this group is not listed

```
 AccessControlListData publicationAccessData = publication.AccessControlList; //PublicationData publication

 List<String> publicationGroupIds = publicationAccessData.AccessControlEntries.Select(entry => entry.Trustee.IdRef).ToList();
```

When that group is added on Publication > Security, it is listed with code above.

But problem is next:
The group is removed from Publication > Security tab so there is no any rights assigned to that group.
When same code is run, there is still id of group which is removed.

I tried to restart all service, IIS, clean browser cache...

Any idea? Or explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Reason: It is feature not a bug.

Once we add the some group/user to publication security it is part of publication. If we remove all rights, group/user stays in the list but just column Rights has enum set on None.

So I just filtered results to remove user/group with Rights set on None.